# ASP.NET MVC adding controller disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for web with MVC 5.

When trying to add a new controller to the "Controllers" map in my project, here's what I do:
right click controllers, Add, New Scaffolded Item, "MVC 5 controller with views using EE". I fill in the Controller Name, Model class etc.. But the "Add" button is greyed out.

- The project is selected.
- I'm not in debugging mode
- I'm able to add a class to Models folder

Answer (score 17):

The option to add a new Controller will be grayed out if your project is currently running.  Stop execution and the option you describe should become available.

Comment: I am trying to add when the project is not in run mode. Still not able to add it.

Comment: @Indigenuity The option isn't even available when running in code so this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the model needs to be created prior to adding the scaffolding. I bet it works if you pick an existing model.

Comment: This isn't a very high quality answer. Please read [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AgataB how is it not a high quality answer? This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a model class first
Add a new scaffolded item 
Attach the new model class
Follow rest of the pop up window and the "Add" button becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just click **Add > Controller..**  or if for some reason its not there **Add > New Item.. > MVC 4 Controller Class**

Is there a particular reason you **MVC 5 controller with views using EE** because on my VS 2013 I do not even see that option?

Comment: Yes I have to do it via add > new scaffolded item > mvc5 with views.. The screen pops up, to fill in extra information, I just can't confirm. The final "Add" button is greyed out.. I'm doing it like this because it says so in asp.net/mvc tutorial